# R package for geographic regions

Tags: r, region, italy

Someone told me about a R package with the definition of objects some regions and nations boundaries. I'm trying to find the border of Veneto, an italian region. What's the name of the package? Do you know an alternative way to find that border (I'm not sure that Veneto is included in the package)??

Comment: Just because you mentioned Veneto and using **R**, there's a [paper](http://gisandscience.com/2011/08/05/statistical-analysis-of-temporal-and-spatial-trends-of-zoonotic-agents-in-animals-and-food/) called "Statistical Analysis of Temporal and Spatial Trends of Zoonotic Agents in Animals and Food". This was conducted in Veneto and used the **R** and **Stata** packages. Might be useful, might be useless :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the specific boundary that you are after but I believe that you are referring to the "maps" package.

If there is not adequate detail in the maps datasets, there is a supplementary package "mapdata" with a [worldHires](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/mapdata/docs/worldHires) dataset. From the package description: "This world database comes from a cleaned-up version of the CIA World Data Bank II data and contains approximately 2 million points representing the world coastlines and national boundaries. This makes it suitable for extracting countries, continents, etc. while still retaining lots of detail."